# Aheadworks Blog - Retrieving Category id and identifier on blog category view

Tags: ce-1.7.0.2, extensions

I am working with the AW Blog extension ( http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/blog-community-edition-by-aheadworks.html ) and trying to find a way to retrieve the ID (should be a number) and the 'identifier' (the URL key) of the current blog category I am on when viewing a Blog category page, on the aw_blog/cat.phtml template file or any other template file I might call on that page (eg. a block in the sidebar, etc.)

Something in the form of:

`<?php echo $currentBlogCat->getId(); ?>`

and/or

`<?php echo $currentBlogCat->getData('identifier'); ?>` would be great.

I've tried searching through discussion boards and not had any luck yet. Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks very much!

I'm using CE 1.7.0.2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try to use

```
$currentBlogCat = Mage::getSingleton('blog/cat');
```

the use your methods on that object.
I know it seams wrong but it looks like this is how the guys at AW implemented it.

Comment: Sorry for extremely late response and thanks for your help!! I ended up using this method, `$currentBlogCat['title']` gives category title etc...